# How to use a single fstream for creation, reading and writing a file

Tags: c++, fstream

I would like to access a file through `fstream` with the following requirements:

- If the files does not exists, it create it
- The file can be read (from pos 0)
- The file can be (over)written (from pos 0)
- Without closing and re-opening the file

`ios_base::in` seems to disable file creation
`ios_base::out` seems to disable file reading

**Is this possible? How?**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cassert>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   auto mode = ios_base::in|ios_base::out;
   std::string filePath = "./test.txt";
   std::string content1 = "Any content 1";
   std::string content2 = "Any content 2";

   {
        std::remove(filePath.c_str());
   }

   {// Test creation
       // make sure test.txt is missing / does not exists
       fstream file(filePath, mode);
       assert(file.is_open() && file.good());
       file << content1;
   }

   { // Test reading & writing
       fstream file(filePath, mode);

       // read
       file.seekg(0);
       std::stringstream buffer1;
       buffer1 << file.rdbuf();
       cout << buffer1.str() << endl;
       assert(buffer1.str()==content1);

       // write
       file.seekp(0);
       file << content2;
       assert(file.is_open() && file.good());

       // read
       file.seekg(0);
       std::stringstream buffer2;
       buffer2 << file.rdbuf();
       cout << buffer2.str() << endl;
       assert(buffer2.str()==content2);
   }

    return 0;
}
```

[Run it](https://onlinegdb.com/S1_zApGhB)

Comment: I think the [example code from cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream#Example) does exactly what you're asking for.

Comment: Well, it truncate the file, so what is the point in reading an empty file?

Comment: Oh, you want to keep any existing content.Yeah, I don't think it's going to create a nonexistent file in in/out mode without `trunc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only with fstream I'd say no.

You might want to have something similar with the trunc mode but you'll lose everything if the file exists (which might be a problem, if not go for trunc + out)

The other way is to check if the file exists, if not you create it (whichever way). Then you open with In and Out and do your stuff.

It kind of doesn't make sense to be able to read inside an empty file you just created from the cpp point of view

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
Just to answer: "It kind of doesn't make sense to be able to read inside an empty file you just created" -> the first time it would just read nothing, but the second time (your run the executable) it would read some previous content right?

Comment: Yes it would in that case. Since it's possible in C with open(2) and probably other libs in C++, it was more of a wild guess